# Can anyone suggest why my function is returning an empty list. I am trying to find all the prime numbers between two given numbers

Tags: python

```py
def prime():
    
    a=int(input("enter the first number"))
    b=int(input('enter the second number'))
    prime_list=[]
    
    for data in range(a,b+1):#5,6,7,8,9,10
        for num in range(1,data):#1,2,3,4
            if data%num==0:
                break
            else:
                prime_list.append(data)
    
    return prime_list

prime()
```

Expecting the function to provide the list of appended values, currently it returns empty list

Comment: @sbottingota - You mean `if not data % num:`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `for` loop with an `if-else` condition from your code

```
for num in range(1,data):#1,2,3,4
    if data%num==0:
        break
    else:
        prime_list.append(data)
```

Problem #1: You cannot exclude numbers divisible by 1. Every number is divisible by 1 (N = 1*N), even the primes.

Problem #2: a `for-else` loop should be used instead. The logic is: break out of the loop if the tested number is divisible by something ==> the number is prime only if there was no break in the loop.

```
for num in range(2,data): #2,3,4
    if data%num==0:
        break
else: # this means: no break in the for loop
    prime_list.append(data)
```

Note that it does not work properly for number 1 (and smaller). 1 is not prime by definition. Also it is quite inefficient.